# Unable to call a command (cmd) to change the resolution in GoCD using

Tags: automation, go-cd

I am trying to execute my automation testing in GoCD using my virtual app server. When I execute on Virtual VM screen execution changes to 1024x697 and due to that my execution fails because of dimension change and result into element is not found. I have tried using multiple ways shown below. Later I found was I can change it before I execute using the command prompt. I tried using that but it fails.

Is there any solution through which I can make this change?

Previous ways to change screen resolution

```
1. chromeOptions.AddArgument("--window-size=1600,900");
2. Driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1600, 900);
```

Command Prompt Execution

```
/c
Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1366 -Height 768 -Force
```

[image]

Error for Command prompt execution

> 'Set-DisplayResolution' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

Apache License, Version 2.0.
Go Version: 18.9.0 (7478-f202ea9416939d7ce356cf3939239ef953ec423b)

Answer (score 0):

[`Set-DisplayResolution`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servercore/set-displayresolution?view=win10-ps) seems to be a powershell module/command, not an executable that can be called directly `cmd`.

You could try running it as a [powershell one-liner by explicitly invoking `powershell`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391613/one-liner-powershell-script) (and include the `-Force` option to avoid interactivity).

Comment: I tried but didn't work out `/c "powershell.exe –NoProfile -command \"Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1024 -Height 768 -Force\""`